# Use PowerShell script to backup SQL Server 2019 Express database to a network destination

Tags: sql-server, backup, powershell

I've got a SQL database server (SQL Server 2019 Express) and a application server connected by a simple switch. Now I'd like to back up a SQL database to the application server.

Since its an SQL Server Express, I've got a powershell script to back up the database and want to run it with the windows task scheduler once every day.

This is the script:

```
$serverName = "PC01\Zenon_2019"
$dbName = "Test_DB"
$backupDirectory = "\\PC02\IMM_Backup"
$daysToStoreBackups = 7

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
 
$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $serverName


Get-ChildItem "$backupDirectory\*.bak" |? { $_.lastwritetime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysToStoreBackups)} |% {Remove-Item $_ -force }
"removed all previous backups older than $daysToStoreBackups days"

$timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss
$targetPath = $backupDirectory + "\" + $dbName + "_" + $timestamp + ".bak"

$smoBackup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
$smoBackup.Action = "Database"
$smoBackup.BackupSetDescription = "Full Backup of " + $dbName
$smoBackup.BackupSetName = $dbName + " Backup"
$smoBackup.Database = $dbName
$smoBackup.MediaDescription = "Disk"
$smoBackup.Devices.AddDevice($targetPath, "File")
$smoBackup.SqlBackup($server) 
"backed up $dbName ($serverName) to $targetPath"`
```

When I'm changing the `$backupDirectory` to a local folder, the script works perfectly fine. But as soon as I change it to the network destination, this error appears:

```
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "SqlBackup" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Backup failed for Server 'PC01\Zenon_2019'. "
In C:\SQL_Backup\script\backup_script.ps1:31 Zeichen:1
+ $smoBackup.SqlBackup($server)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

I've already tested some things:

- Create Files via PowerShell console in "\PC02\IMM_Backup" is working.
- I've changed the sharing options of the folder to full access for anyone but its still not working.

I would be happy to get any ideas or solutions for this problem!

Comment: Check the NTFS permissions too. Those are independent on SMB permissions.

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have permissions to the `\\PC02\IMM_Backup` share?.

Comment: Consider calling dbo.DatabaseBackup from https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html It won't help you with permissions on network location but help you not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've set the sharing options to full access for anyone. This should include the SQL service account, right? How could I grant access to a specific SQL service account?

Comment: For the file sharing, I think you will need to set permissions on the actual folder in addition to the Share permissions.  Though I could be wrong about this.to In line with what Sergey has said, have you considered using dbatools for your backup: https://docs.dbatools.io/Backup-DbaDatabase? Like Ola Hallengren's script, it contains a lot of built in features so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. It does not, however, contain a file retention policy parameter, which  dbo.DatabaseBackup does.